# Optimization problem, finding the dimensions of the container of least cost.

Tags: optimization, applications

A  closed  rectangular  container  with  a  square  base  is  to  have  a  volume  of  $2000$  cubic centimeters.  It costs twice as much per square centimeter for the top and bottom as it does for the sides.  Find the dimensions of the container of least cost.

So the formula for the volume is: $2000 = x^{2}\cdot y$
and formula for cost (area) is $4xy+4x^{2}$.
After some substitutions and taking the derivative of the cost formula, I found that there is one critical number for $x = 10$, and substituting back to volume formula, I found that $y = 20$.

But now, i need to show that $10$ is the absolute minimum, I'm confused about how do I need to show that? Just plug in back to the original cost formula? It will just give me another number, which does not help at all.

Comment: Area is 4xy+2x^2, you made an error in equation. You need to find derivative and equate to 0.

Comment: @Moti No, its not. Since it costs twice twice as much per top and bottom as it does for the sides. I found the derivative and equated it to 0. And then i found the only critical number (10), but how do i prove that 10 is the absolute minimum?

Comment: You are right with the equation. Replace y by using the first equation and than with derivative find the max/min

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At *any* local minimum not on a boundary, the derivative is $0$. There is no boundary in this problem, so finding where the derivative is $0$ gives you all the local minima.

The absolute minimum is also a local minimum. So to find it, you find all the local extrema, evaluate the function at each of them, and choose the smallest value. That have has to be the absolute minimum. In this problem, the derivative is $0$ at only one location: $x = 10$. So assuming this point is a local minimum, it must be the absolute minimum.

So the only thing more that you need to do is confirm that $x = 10$ is indeed a minimum (it could also be a maximum, or an inflection point). The easiest way to do that is to take the second derivative: $$C''(x) = \frac{16000}{x^3} + 8$$ In particular $C''(10) = 24 > 0$. Since it is positive, $x = 10$ is a minimum, and because it is the only minimum, it is the absolute minimum.

Comment: so if the are no boundaries, then the critical points will be abs max/min ?

Comment: No. The critical points will be all the maximums and minimums. The absolute maximums and minimums will be among them, assuming they exist at all, so you just take the largest and smallest. In this case, there is only one critical point, so it has to be an absolute extrema, which turns out to be a minimum (the function has no maximum).

Comment: So if we have two critical points and boundaries at all, then we will have no abs max/min values?

Comment: No. You just have to do more to find them. If you have boundaries on both sides, and since your function is differentiable by assumption (which in particular implies it is continuous), you are actually guaranteed to have an absolute max and an absolute min. It is only when you have no boundary on at least one side that it might not have one or the other. To be clear here: a boundary is a point where the function is defined, but not beyond it. If the function is undefined at a point (such as $C$ is at $x = 0$), that is unbounded.

Comment: When you have both boundaries, find all critical points, and add the two boundary points to them. Find the values of all the points. The largest is the absolute maximum. The least is the absolute minimum. When you don't have a boundary on one side, then you need to consider the behavior of the function as it approaches that side (or $\pm\infty$ to determine if the function has an absolute min or max.